# HL7 message type for retrieve data

Tags: xml, hl7

I'm working on a HL7 system and the client want a HL7 message for retrieve glucommeters data.
I will provide it in XML format from an external application.

What type of HL7 message should i use?

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of variables influencing the answer to this question.  Are you using HL7 v2 or v3?  If v3, the answer probably depends on what country you're in.

For example, in Canada, using HL7 v3, a glucommeter reading is probably considered to be a basic observation, and you'd probably use a Patient Basic Observation Query (REPC_IN000054CA) to access a reading that had previously been taken. Or a Record Patient Basic Observation Request message (REPC_IN000051CA) to record a new measure.

Comment: Should be a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are probably using HL7 version 2.xx (like 99.99% of the rest of the world). The message type you will want to use is very, very likely ORU (Observation Result Unsolicited). Don't let the "Unsolicited" fool you, this is also the same message type used for all Lab Results, Pathology Results, Radiology Results, etc.

Remember that's the Message Type (MSH Field 9 Component 1). The Message EVENT (MSH Field 9 Component 2) is typically either BLANK or R01 for this type of message.

Hope this helps you.